# MySQL is pretty slow after 50-100k rows whats happen?

Tags: mysql, innodb, stored-procedures, index-tuning, uuid

I have been trying now many times, and I tried to find a way to make sense of and find out my problem. But the problem is still performance issues.

I tested it on a developer server ( 2 cores, 4gb ram ) but I still got issues and problems, here is the stored procedure I have typed.

```sql
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertDistributorProduct;
    
    DELIMITER $$
    
    CREATE PROCEDURE insertDistributorProduct(
        distributorUUID VARCHAR(36),
        distributorTitle VARCHAR(256),
        distributorDescription TEXT,
        distributorSKU VARCHAR(128),
        manufacturer VARCHAR(64),
        manufacturerSKU VARCHAR(128),
        productEan BIGINT(20),
        productCostPrice INT(11),
        productStock INT(11),
        productStockExpected DATE
    )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE _manufacturerUUID VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE _distributorProductUUID VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL;
        
        SET _manufacturerUUID = ( SELECT m.manufacturerUUID FROM manufacturer m
                WHERE LOWER(m.manufacturerTitle) = LOWER(manufacturer) LIMIT 1 );
    
        -- If manufacturer not exists insert it
        IF ( _manufacturerUUID IS NULL ) THEN
            
            SET _manufacturerUUID = ( SELECT ma.manufacturerUUID FROM manufacturerAlias ma
                    WHERE LOWER(ma.aliasTitle) = LOWER(manufacturer) LIMIT 1 );
            
            -- _manufacturerUUID not found in manufacturer and _manufacturerAlias so insert
            IF ( _manufacturerUUID IS NULL ) THEN
            
                SET _manufacturerUUID = UUID();
                
                INSERT INTO manufacturer(manufacturerUUID,manufacturerTitle,added)
                VALUES(_manufacturerUUID,manufacturer,NOW());
                
            END IF;
                
        END IF;
            
        SET _distributorProductUUID = ( SELECT dp.distributorProductUUID FROM distributorProduct dp
                WHERE dp.distributorUUID = distributorUUID
                  AND LOWER(dp.distributorSKU) = LOWER(distributorSKU) );
        
        -- Update distributorProduct if its all ready found
        IF ( _distributorProductUUID IS NOT NULL ) THEN
    
            UPDATE 
                distributorProduct dp
            
            SET 
                dp.distributorTitle = distributorTitle,
                dp.distributorDescription = distributorDescription,
                dp.manufacturerUUID = _manufacturerUUID,
                dp.manufacturerSKU = manufacturerSKU,
                dp.productEan = productEan,
                dp.productCostPrice = productCostPrice,
                dp.productStock = productStock,
                dp.productStockExpected = productStockExpected,
                dp.updated = NOW(),
                dp.activated = 1
                
            WHERE
                dp.distributorProductUUID = _distributorProductUUID
            
            LIMIT
                1;
        
        -- Insert new product to distributorProduct if not exists.
        ELSE
        
            INSERT INTO distributorProduct (distributorProductUUID,distributorUUID,manufacturerUUID,distributorTitle,distributorDescription,distributorSKU,manufacturerSKU,productEan,productCostPrice,productStock,productStockExpected,added)
            VALUES(UUID(),distributorUUID,_manufacturerUUID,distributorTitle,distributorDescription,distributorSKU,manufacturerSKU,productEan,productCostPrice,productStock,productStockExpected,NOW());
        
        END IF;
        
    END
    $$
```

My problem is that every time I have over 50-100k rows, this script takes longer and longer over time, and I have to try to look up my index but still nothing happens.

How can I debug and improve the performance of my database? Every day I need to run this producer like 1-1,4milion times between 4-5 hours max, it updates all our products but right now it's useless.

The first time 60k rows take 15min, and after that 60k more ( total 120k )  it takes approx 30-45min to run, and I still don't know why it happened.  What did I do wrong?

Everything I tested here is running in a virtual box software, I don't have to test this on real hardware.

Comment: Have you tried committing every ~5k records?

Comment: What you mean when you say committing every 5k records? like transaction begin ...... commit ?

Comment: The procedure seems to insert 2 rows only, 1 in each table. Do you run it 100k times?

Comment: this procedure will be running like 1-1,4 million times every day so after 50-100k times its make perfomes issues :/

Comment: i found the issue, its because VirtualBox not have the perfume, i have normal hardware right now ( 1x Xeon dual-core HT ( 4 cores ), 8gb ddr2, 1x 1tb HHD ( no SSD ) and the same setup perfume like 53% faster then VirtualBox do wit 6 cores, 8gb ram and flash-drive(ssd) thanks a lot to all helping!

Comment: You mean perform, not perfume, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is what happened:

```
UUID VARCHAR(36)
```

UUIDs (GUIDs, MD5s, etc) are *very* random.  That is, if you can't keep the entire table (or index) cached in RAM, the 'next' lookup is likely to cause a disk hit.  And disk hits are a big factor (think 90%) of the cost of performing queries.

More discussion [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid).  That includes a few partial remedies.

**More importantly**

```
WHERE LOWER(ma.aliasTitle) = LOWER(manufacturer)
```

has terrible performance because it hides an indexable column inside a function (`LOWER()`).  Instead, make sure those two columns have a collation ending with `_ci` (as in "Case Insensitive").  Then simply do

```
WHERE ma.aliasTitle = manufacturer
```

and have

```
INDEX(aliasTitle)
INDEX(manufacturerTitle)
INDEX(distributorSKU)
```

If you run into some index limit size, please provide MySQL version and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Meanwhile, `distributorTitle VARCHAR(256)` is likely to cause trouble.  Changing to `(255)` may work; `(191)` may be needed for 5.5 or 5.6; beware of truncating strings.

One more thing -- When you `CREATE` the procedure, be sure to have established the collation for the connection that is consistent with the columns.  For example, if you are using `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci` for the columns, then you could do it this way:

```
SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
DELIMITER //
CREATE ...
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That is a theoretical issue - but with 100k rows it should be a total non issue unless you run mysql on a 10 year old smartphone or something like that. The amount of data is waaaay too small to not just allow caching everything in memory, particularly with the times involved.

Comment: Thanks @TomTom; that prompted me to comment on the _real_ problems:  don't hide columns in functions; add indexes; establish collation for proc.

Answer (score 0):

Having experienced this myself ion Firebird, I would suggest that the problem is transaction and isolation levels.

The default transaction used by MySQL is **Autocommit** with an isolation of **Repeatable_Read**.

1. [Autocommit, Commit and Rollback](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html#:%7E:text=If%20autocommit%20mode%20is%20enabled,did%20not%20return%20an%20error.)
2. [Transaction Isolation Levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html)

You should at the very least change the isolation level to perhaps **Read Committed**, otherwise more of the table may get locked, which can slow things down.

> For other search conditions, InnoDB locks the index range scanned, using gap locks or next-key locks to block insertions by other sessions into the gaps covered by the range. For information about gap locks and next-key locks, see Section 15.7.1, “InnoDB Locking”.

From 2 above.

It's also a good idea to control the transaction yourself, so bracket your code inside the stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
...
BEGIN
 START TRANSACTION;
  ...
 COMMIT;
END
```